# QGIS crashing when runing a loop to perfom select by location with PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, select-by-location, extract-by-mask

I have written a script to divide United States into a grid of 200 km, then in each grid will contain a certain number of mobile towers with (lat and long). The script must then select each grid and perform select by location and output a shapefile with the assigned id. When I run this for one specif ID, let's (id ==1) the codes does it well, but when I run it to loop for all the grid I get a crash message.

[image]
The stack trace message is:

```
Stack Trace


QMap::value qmap.h:656
QgsProcessingAlgorithm::checkParameterValues qgsprocessingalgorithm.cpp:102
meth_QgsProcessingAlgorithm_checkParameterValues sip_corepart4.cpp:93536
PyMethodDef_RawFastCallKeywords :
PyMethodDef_RawFastCallKeywords :
PyEval_EvalFrameDefault :
PyEval_EvalCodeWithName :
PyMethodDef_RawFastCallKeywords :
PyEval_EvalFrameDefault :
PyEval_EvalCodeWithName :
PyMethodDef_RawFastCallKeywords :
PyEval_EvalFrameDefault :
PyEval_EvalCodeWithName :
PyEval_EvalCodeEx :
PyEval_EvalCode :
PyArena_Free :
PyRun_StringFlags :
PyImport_Import :
PyImport_Import :
PyMethodDef_RawFastCallKeywords :
PyMethodDef_RawFastCallKeywords :
PyEval_EvalFrameDefault :
PyEval_EvalCodeWithName :
PyImport_Import :
PyImport_Import :
PyMethodDef_RawFastCallKeywords :
PyMethodDef_RawFastCallKeywords :
PyEval_EvalFrameDefault :
PyMethodDef_RawFastCallKeywords :
PyEval_EvalFrameDefault :
PyEval_EvalCodeWithName :
PyMethodDef_RawFastCallKeywords :
PyEval_EvalFrameDefault :
PyEval_EvalCodeWithName :
PyMethodDef_RawFastCallKeywords :
PyEval_EvalFrameDefault :
PyMethodDef_RawFastCallKeywords :
PyEval_EvalFrameDefault :
PyMethodDef_RawFastCallKeywords :
PyEval_EvalFrameDefault :
PyFunction_FastCallDict :
PyMethodDef_RawFastCallDict :
PyObject_Call :
PyInit_QtCore :
PyInit_QtCore :
PyInit_QtCore :
PyInit_QtCore :
PyInit_QtCore :
QMetaObject::activate :
QAction::activate :
QAbstractButton::click :
QAbstractButton::mouseReleaseEvent :
QToolButton::mouseReleaseEvent :
QWidget::event :
QApplicationPrivate::notify_helper :
QApplication::notify :
QgsApplication::notify qgsapplication.cpp:475
QCoreApplication::notifyInternal2 :
QApplicationPrivate::sendMouseEvent :
QSizePolicy::QSizePolicy :
QSizePolicy::QSizePolicy :
QApplicationPrivate::notify_helper :
QApplication::notify :
QgsApplication::notify qgsapplication.cpp:475
QCoreApplication::notifyInternal2 :
QGuiApplicationPrivate::processMouseEvent :
QWindowSystemInterface::sendWindowSystemEvents :
QEventDispatcherWin32::processEvents :
UserCallWinProcCheckWow :
DispatchMessageWorker :
QEventDispatcherWin32::processEvents :
qt_plugin_query_metadata :
QEventLoop::exec :
QCoreApplication::exec :
main main.cpp:1638
BaseThreadInitThunk :
RtlUserThreadStart :




QGIS Info
QGIS Version: 3.18.2-Z�rich
QGIS code revision: 515138c171
Compiled against Qt: 5.11.2
Running against Qt: 5.11.2
Compiled against GDAL: 3.1.4
Running against GDAL: 3.1.4



System Info
CPU Type: x86_64
Kernel Type: winnt
Kernel Version: 10.0.19042
```

I would like to hear your thoughts.
Find the code bellow.

```
from qgis.core import QgsVectorLayer, QgsProject

project = QgsProject.instance()

project.removeAllMapLayers()


countriesPath = "D:/GIS_T/scripting_qgis/ne_10m_admin_0_countries.shp"

usTowersPath = "D:/GIS_T/scripting_qgis/us_towers.shp"

countries = QgsVectorLayer(countriesPath, 'World countries', 'ogr')

us_towers = QgsVectorLayer(usTowersPath, 'US Cell Towers', 'ogr')

currentCellTowerFields = QgsFields()
currentCellTowerFields.append(QgsField("tower_id", QVariant.Int))
currentCellTowerFields.append( QgsField("cell_id", QVariant.Int))
currentCellTowerFields.append(QgsField("cell_centroid_lon", QVariant.Double))
currentCellTowerFields.append(QgsField("cell_centroid_lat", QVariant.Double))
currentCellTowerFields.append(QgsField("tower_lon", QVariant.Double))
currentCellTowerFields.append(QgsField("tower_lat", QVariant.Double))
currentCellTowerFields.append(QgsField("radio", QVariant.String))
currentCellTowerFields.append(QgsField("tower_to_cell_centroid_dist_km", QVariant.Double))

crs = QgsProject.instance().crs()
transform_context = QgsProject.instance().transformContext()
save_options = QgsVectorFileWriter.SaveVectorOptions()
save_options.driverName = "ESRI Shapefile"
save_options.fileEncoding = "UTF-8"


project.addMapLayer(countries)

usLayer = QgsVectorLayer("Polygon", "The US", "memory")
usLayerProvider = usLayer.dataProvider()

countriesLayer = project.mapLayersByName("World countries")[0]

countriesLayer.selectByExpression('"SOVEREIGNT" = \'United States of America\'')


us_features = countriesLayer.getSelectedFeatures()
for feature in us_features:
    usLayerProvider.addFeature(feature)

usLayerProvider.updateExtents()

countriesLayer.removeSelection()
project.removeMapLayer(countries)


#coordenadas do poligno de corte
splitPolygon = QgsVectorLayer("Polygon", "US Mainland Split Polygon", "memory")
splitPolygonProvider = splitPolygon.dataProvider()
splitPolygonFeature = QgsFeature()

#coordenadas tiradas manualmente
splitPolygonFeature.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPolygonXY([[
QgsPointXY(-127.5,52.4),
QgsPointXY(-127.5,14.0), 
QgsPointXY((-127.5 - 60.9) / 2,14.0),
QgsPointXY(-60.9,(52.4 + 14.0) / 2),
QgsPointXY(-60.9,52.4)
]]))

splitPolygonProvider.addFeature(splitPolygonFeature)
splitPolygon.updateExtents()

project.addMapLayer(usLayer)

to_be_clipped = project.mapLayersByName('The US')[0]
project.addMapLayer(splitPolygon)

#execusao do clip
clip_mask = project.mapLayersByName('US Mainland Split Polygon')[0]

main_land_us = processing.run("native:clip",{
'INPUT': to_be_clipped,
'OVERLAY': clip_mask,
'OUTPUT': 'memory:'
})

project.addMapLayer(main_land_us['OUTPUT'])
project.mapLayersByName('output')[0].setName('US Mainland')

project.removeMapLayer(usLayer)
project.removeMapLayer(splitPolygon)

iface.zoomFull()

#adicionamos as torres
project.addMapLayer(us_towers)



to_be_extracted = us_towers #project.mapLayersByName('US Cell Towers')[0]
extract_mask = project.mapLayersByName('US Mainland')[0]
mainLandTowers = processing.run("native:extractbylocation", \
{'INPUT': to_be_extracted,'PREDICATE': 6, 'INTERSECT': extract_mask, \
'OUTPUT': 'memory:'})

project.addMapLayer(mainLandTowers['OUTPUT'])
project.mapLayersByName('output')[0].setName('US Mainland Cell Towers')

#criamos os grids, com as suas dimensoes
us_mainland = project.mapLayersByName("US Mainland")[0]
createdGrid = processing.run("native:creategrid",{
'TYPE': 2,
'EXTENT': us_mainland.id(),
'HSPACING': 1.802,
'VSPACING': 1.802,
'HOVERLAY': 0,
'VOVERLAY': 0,
'CRS': 'EPSG:4326',
'OUTPUT': 'memory:'
})

project.addMapLayer(createdGrid['OUTPUT'])
project.mapLayersByName('output')[0].setName('Grid cells')

#A camada da grelha, composta por celulas
cells = project.mapLayersByName('Grid cells')[0]


#camada das torres
allCellTowers = QgsVectorLayer("Point", \
    "All cell towers", \
    "memory")
#Adicionamos os campos da camada   
allCellTowersProvider = allCellTowers.dataProvider()
allCellTowersProvider.addAttributes([\
    QgsField("tower_id", QVariant.Int),\
    QgsField("cell_id", QVariant.Int),\
    QgsField("cell_centroid_lon", QVariant.Double),\
    QgsField("cell_centroid_lat", QVariant.Double),\
    QgsField("tower_lon", QVariant.Double),\
    QgsField("tower_lat", QVariant.Double),\
    QgsField("radio", QVariant.String),\
    QgsField("tower_to_cell_centroid_dist_km", QVariant.Double)])
allCellTowers.updateFields()

us_mainland_towers = project.mapLayersByName('US Mainland Cell Towers')[0]
to_be_extracted = us_mainland_towers

for i in range(0,3):


    for cell in cells.getFeatures():
        #if (cell.attribute('id') == 1):
        if (cell.attribute('id') == i):
            
            print('ID: ', cell.attribute('id'))
            print('Area: ', cell.geometry().area())
            print('Perimeter: ', cell.geometry().length())
            print('Centroid: ', cell.geometry().centroid())

            cid = str(cell.attribute('id'))
            cell_centroid = cell.geometry().centroid().asPoint()
            cell_centroid_lon = cell_centroid.x()
            cell_centroid_lat = cell_centroid.y()
            #Celula temporaria que usamos para extrair as torres que estao na grelha actual
            tempCell = QgsVectorLayer("Polygon", \
            "Cell " + cid, \
            "memory")
            tempCellProvider = tempCell.dataProvider()
            tempCellProvider.addFeature(cell)
            tempCellProvider.updateExtents()
            project.addMapLayer(tempCell)
            #Celula temporaria dos pontos que estao dentro da grelha temporaria
            tempCellTowers = QgsVectorLayer("Point", \
            "Cell " + cid + " towers", \
            "memory")
            tempCellTowersProvider = tempCellTowers.dataProvider()
            tempCellTowersProvider.addAttributes([\
            QgsField("tower_id", QVariant.Int),\
            QgsField("cell_id", QVariant.Int),\
            QgsField("cell_centroid_lon", QVariant.Double),\
            QgsField("cell_centroid_lat", QVariant.Double),\
            QgsField("tower_lon", QVariant.Double),\
            QgsField("tower_lat", QVariant.Double),\
            QgsField("radio", QVariant.String),\
            QgsField("tower_to_cell_centroid_dist_km", QVariant.Double)])
            tempCellTowers.updateFields()
            
            d = QgsDistanceArea()
            d.setEllipsoid('WGS84')
            #Extracao das torres da celula temporaria actual
            #us_mainland_towers = project.mapLayersByName('US Mainland Cell Towers')[0]
            #to_be_extracted = us_mainland_towers
            extract_mask = tempCell
            extractedTempCellTowers = processing.run("native:extractbylocation", \
            {'INPUT': to_be_extracted,'PREDICATE': 6, \
            'INTERSECT': extract_mask, \
            'OUTPUT': 'memory:'})
            
            project.addMapLayer(extractedTempCellTowers['OUTPUT'])
            extractedTempCellTowers = project.mapLayersByName('output')[0]
            #Contar o nr das torres que foram encontradas na celula temporaria
            count = extractedTempCellTowers.featureCount()
            if (count > 0):
                allTowersCount = allCellTowers.featureCount()
                for ect in extractedTempCellTowers.getFeatures():
                    allTowersCount += 1
                    radio = ect['radio']
                    ect.setAttribute(0, allTowersCount)
                    ect.setAttribute(1, int(cid))
                    ect.setAttribute(2, cell_centroid_lon)
                    ect.setAttribute(3, cell_centroid_lat)
                    towerLoc = ect.geometry().asPoint()
                    ect.setAttribute(4, towerLoc.x())
                    ect.setAttribute(5, towerLoc.y())
                    #print(ect['radio'])
                    #radio = ect.attribute('radio')
                    ect.setAttribute(6, radio)
                    ect.setAttribute(7, d.convertLengthMeasurement(\
                    d.measureLine(towerLoc, cell_centroid), \
                    QgsUnitTypes.DistanceKilometers))
                    tempCellTowersProvider.addFeature(ect)
                    
                tempCellTowersProvider.updateExtents()
                
                if(count == 1):
                    print("Grid Cell", cid, "has", count, "tower")
                else:
                    print("Grid Cell", cid, "has", count, "towers")
               
                writer = QgsVectorFileWriter.create("D:/GIS_T/scripting_qgis/Ids/Cell " + cid + " Towers.shp",currentCellTowerFields,\
                    QgsWkbTypes.Point,crs,transform_context,save_options)

                if writer.hasError() != QgsVectorFileWriter.NoError:
                    print("Error when creating shapefile: ", writer.errorMessage())

                 
                
                #project.addMapLayer(tempCellTowers)
                for tower in tempCellTowers.getFeatures():
                    writer.addFeature(tower)
                    allCellTowersProvider.addFeature(tower)
                allCellTowersProvider.updateExtents()
                del writer
                project.addMapLayer(allCellTowers)
                #iface.showAttributeTable(allCellTowers)
            
            
            else:
                print("Grid Cell ", cid, "has no tower")
                
            project.removeMapLayer(project.mapLayersByName('output')[0])
            project.removeMapLayer(project.mapLayersByName('US Cell Towers')[0])
            project.removeMapLayer(project.mapLayersByName('US Mainland Cell Towers')[0])
            project.removeMapLayer(project.mapLayersByName('Cell ' + cid)[0])
```

Comment: For help with this I think we'll need not only that but for you to reduce your full code to a [code snippet](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312) that produces the same error message.

Comment: Wouldnt it be easier to intersect the grid with your mobile towers, then extract by attribute?

Comment: we also need to see the **text** of the stacktrace that is partly visible in your picture

Comment: I have added the stack trace in the question.